# Javascript split freezing the browser

Tags: javascript

I am have a big string in 5000 line divided by **\n** thought **textarea**
here i am want to convert this big string to array.

My string is like this

```
query= '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n6...........';
```

so I am converting as:

```
var array = query.split('\n');
console.log(array);
```

But it's freezing the browser for 30 second after that it's showing on console.

After converting in string I am sending data one by one to server by POST and after validation I am displaying result one by one.

**So if anyone knows its better methods then tell me otherwise help me prevent browser from freezing.**

Demo link but not working, you can see my html and js code

https://jsfiddle.net/7ne9L4Lj/40/

Comment: ok now i have removed but still freezing, i was use 5000 for first 5000 value

Comment: Can you please share code for sending n processing response? That might be source of problem you are facing. Split should not take 30 seconds in this case.

Comment: This takes less than a second on Chrome  http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bmter4e9/

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: I have jsfiddle demo, it is not working but you all can see code

Comment: I think you need to revalidate you complete logic .. issue is not about the `split` function here. please rethink of send 5000 ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A split of 5000 lines takes less than a second, at least on Chrome: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bmter4e9/)

HOWEVER having AJAX inside an each is a super bad idea unless you like to flood your server

```
 $.each(array, function (index, value) {
    $.ajax({
```

instead do

```
function sendIt() {
  if (array.length==0) return; // stop
  var value = array.pop();
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {
      ...
      send();
    }
    ...
  });
}

$(function() {
  $("#formID").on("submit",function(e) { // give the form an ID
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submission

    ....

    sendIt();
    ....
  })
});
```

Comment: can you please provide me with example pop because i have tried myself many time but not get success

Comment: What pop? Please elaborate